# Multi Slider in React Native. (Need some tips)

Tags: react-native, slider

Hello everyone im trying to create a multiple marker slider in react native. I searched for packages etc, but only found with 1 or 2 markers maximum.
Image is from google. Im trying to create something similar with this.
[image]
Where red cant go pass oranges etc. I have a working example in web using Material's UI Slider but cant find anything to make it work in native.